# How to assign a variable name using another variable?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to assign a variable name using a variable but it is not working:

```
name_of_variable = abc;

eval(name_of_variable) = 'simpleword'; 

console.log(abc);
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: There are few good reasons to do that. What is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Why do you want to use `eval`?? Also *"not work"* is not a proper description of what the problem is.

Comment: works very thank you

Comment: var data = "abc";
eval("var " + data + "=simpleword;");
 
console.log(abc);